# ASM printf: no output if string doesn't include \n newline

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, printf, att

This piece of code prints Hello on the screen

```
.data
    hello: .string "Hello\n"
    format: .string "%s" 
.text
    .global _start 
    _start:

    push $hello
    push $format
    call printf

    movl $1, %eax   #exit
    movl $0, %ebx
    int $0x80
```

But if I remove '\n' from hello string, like this:

```
.data
    hello: .string "Hello"
    format: .string "%s" 
.text
    .global _start 
    _start:

    push $hello
    push $format
    call printf

    movl $1, %eax   #exit
    movl $0, %ebx
    int $0x80
```

Program doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Define _"doesn't work"_.

Comment: It does not print "Hello"

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't just get overwritten by your shell's prompt? What if you use a really long string (but still without `\n`)?

Comment: Long string doesn't work, and Im sure that it doesn't print anything. I just tried to run both variants on roommates pc, and neither worked.

Comment: @Michael. I am using `gcc -nostartfiles filename` command to compile the code.

Comment: By the way, the format string isn't needed I think...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The exit syscall (equivalent to `_exit` in C) doesn't flush the stdout buffer.

Outputting a newline causes a flush on line-buffered streams, which stdout will be if it is pointed to a terminal.

If you're willing to call `printf` in libc, you shouldn't feel bad about calling `exit` the same way. Having an `int $0x80` in your program doesn't make you a bare-metal badass.

At minimum you need to `push stdout;call fflush` before exiting. Or `push $0;call fflush`. (`fflush(NULL)` flushes all output streams)

Comment: Or use `puts`, or include a newline in what you're printing.  Although that would only fix it for a terminal, not a pipe, so yes, don't mix stdio with raw _exit system calls.  [Using printf in assembly leads to empty output when piping, but works on the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38379553)

Answer (score 3):

You need to clean up the arguments you passed to `printf` and then flush the output buffer since you don't have new line in your string:

```
.data
    hello: .string "Hello"
    format: .string "%s" 
.text
    .global _start 
    _start:

    push $hello
    push $format
    call printf
    addl $8, %esp
    pushl stdout
    call fflush
    addl $4, %esp
    movl $1, %eax   #exit
    movl $0, %ebx
    int $0x80
```

Comment: You don't actually need to clean the stack if you're going to end with an `_exit(0)` system call.  `_start` isn't a function so there's nowhere you can `ret` to anyway.  The only important thing here is `fflush(NULL)` or `fflush(stdout)` before the raw `_exit` syscall (instead of `call exit`).  To be fair, it is important to learn how the stack works if you want to write functions eventually.  So realize that you're leaving stack args unpopped, and instead of another push, you could `movl $0, (%esp)` / `call fflush` to reuse one of the stack slots you reserved by pushing args for printf.