# Using printf in assembly leads to empty output when piping, but works on the terminal

Tags: linux, assembly, printf, x86-64, glibc

([No output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54507957/printf-call-from-assembly-do-not-print-to-stdout) even on the terminal when the output doesn't include a newline has the same cause.)

---

I try to use `printf` from my assembler code, this is a minimal example which should just print `hello` to stdout:

```
.section  .rodata
hello:
    .ascii  "hello\n\0"
.section .text
    .globl _start        
_start:
    movq $hello, %rdi     # first parameter
    xorl %eax, %eax       # 0 - number of used vector registers
    call printf        
#exit   
    movq $60, %rax
    movq $0, %rdi
    syscall
```

I build it with

```
gcc -nostdlib try_printf.s -o try_printf -lc
```

and when I run it, it seems to work: the string `hello` is printed out and the exit status is `0`:

```
XXX$ ./try_printf
hello
XXX$ echo $?
0
XXX$
```

But when I try to capture the text, it is obvious, that something is not working properly:

```
XXX$ output=$(./try_printf) 
XXX$ echo $output

XXX$
```

The variable `output` should have the value `hello`, but is empty.

What is wrong with my usage of `printf`?

Comment: Using syscall to exit doesn't flush the output buffers used by the _C_ runtime. Replace the exit syscall with a `call exit` (exit is part of the _C_ library as well)

Comment: If you review the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html) for `exit` (exit(3)) you'll find this in the description _All open stdio(3) streams are flushed and  closed.   Files  created  by tmpfile(3) are removed._ . This isn't guaranteed when using `movq $60, %rax
    movq $0, %rdi
    syscall`

Comment: A C version of basically same question (with output not ending with newline so it fails even on a terminal): [Why is this simple code working with \`exit\` and is not working with \`\_exit\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36032305).  Also [Printf without newline in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8502945) re: calling fflush(NULL) in asm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Use `call exit` instead of a raw `_exit` syscall after using stdio functions like printf.**  This flushes stdio buffers (`write` system call) before making an `exit_group` system call).

(Or if your program defines a `main` instead of `_start`, returning from `main` is equivalent to calling `exit`.  You can't `ret` from `_start`.)  Calling `fflush(NULL)` should also work.

---

As Michael explained, it is OK to link the C-library dynamically. This is also how it is introduced in the ["Programming bottom up"](http://nongnu.askapache.com/pgubook/ProgrammingGroundUp-1-0-booksize.pdf) book (see chapter 8).

However it is important to call `exit` from the C-library in order to end the program and not to bypass it, which was what I wrongly did by calling `exit-syscall`. As hinted by Michael, exit does a lot of [clean up](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html) like flushing streams.

That is what happened: As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932932/why-does-stdout-need-explicit-flushing-when-redirected-to-file), the C-library buffers the the standard streams as follows:

1. No buffering for standard error.
2. If standard out/in is a terminal, it is line-buffered.
3. **If standard out/in is a not a terminal, it is fully-buffered and thus flush is needed before a raw exit system call.**

Which case applies is decided when `printf` is called for the first time for a stream.

So if `printf_try` is called directly in the terminal, the output of the program can be seen because `hello` has `\n` at the end (which triggers the flush in the line-buffered mode) and it is a terminal, also the 2. case.

Calling `printf_try` via `$(./printf_try)` means that the stdout is no longer a terminal (actually I don't know whether is is a temp file or a memory file) and thus the 3. case is in effect - there is need for an explicit flush i.e. call to C-`exit`.

Comment: Thanks for writing up a nice canonical answer to the exit vs. _exit and stdio buffering question.  Added to the [x86 tag wiki FAQ section](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) so we can find it easily and close future questions as duplicates of this.

Answer (score 2):

The C standard library often contains initialization code for the standard I/O streams — initialization code that you're bypassing by defining your own entry point. Try defining `main` instead of `_start`:

```
    .globl main
main:
    # _start code here.
```

and then build with `gcc try_printf.s -o try_printf` (*i.e.*, without `-nostdlib`).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I would like to use `printf` without the C-runtime and think it should be possible. But you are right, my code seems to miss some initialization/finalization usually done by the C-runtime.

Comment: @ead Unfortunately, it's kind of a given. You're linking with the C standard library anyway, which is the majority of the runtime's size. Take a shot and see how it goes. (You could always use the `write` syscall directly!)

Comment: You cannot use `printf` (or other C runtime functions) without linking the C runtime. Even if you could, it would obviously be a bad idea. The only way to work around this would be to call operating-system API functions instead (which are just wrappers around C runtime functionality linked into the OS).

Comment: @CodyGray : He is linking the _C_ library with `-lc` . On Linux you can get away with it if he isn't building a static executable. When linking dynamically the C libraries shared object will have its initialization routine called when loaded by the dynamic linker. That has the side effect of setting things up to the point that `printf` can work. But I do agree if your going to call _C_ library, don't circumvent the C runtime initialization. Use `main` function and remove the `-nostdlib`.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I was not aware, that `-lc` is linked dynamically. Thanks!