# Printf call from assembly do not print to stdout

Tags: assembly

i am building and running a code in **NASM** on a **x86_64 Linux**.

The program calls the **GNU libc** `printf` function from my program.

The program only must print a sentence to stdout.

```
; comment
section .data
fmt: db "Hello %s %c", 0
name: db "Jane Doe", 0

section .text
global _start
extern printf

func:
lea rdi, [fmt]
lea rsi, [name]
mov rcx, 0x0A
xor rax, rax
call printf
ret

_start:
call func
; exit
mov rax, 1
mov rbx, 0
int 80h
ret
```

Here is the way i compile it :

```
nasm -f elf64 Program.s -o Program.o -Werror 
ld -m elf_x86_64 Program.o -o Program -lc -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

When i run the program, it outputs to the terminal `Hello Jane Doe`. Ok, that is what i am expecting.

But when i redirect the out as following :

```
./Program > output.txt
```

The file `output.txt` is **empty**.

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me    0 output.txt
```

Any idea ? It seems that the libc `printf` is in this case printing into another file descriptor than `stdout` but maybe i am wrong.

## SOLUTION

The solution has been found by a user in the comments.

Switching

```
; exit
mov rax, 1
mov rbx, 0
int 80h
```

by `call exit` did the trick.

Comment: Could be an issue with data not being flushed by printf if it detects that it's writing to a file? Try calling exit instead of `int 80h` (which doesn't call stuff registered by `atexit`)

Comment: Semi-related (not the problem here): the 32-bit `int 0x80` ABI won't work for system calls that need 64-bit pointers.  Use the 64-bit `syscall` ABI.  [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](//stackoverflow.com/q/46087730).  It's perfectly safe for `sys_exit` unless you're on a kernel built without CONFIG_IA32_EMULATION, or Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use C library functions you shouldn't use `_start`, but good old `main`. If you steal `_start` from libc, it won't be able to perform several setup and cleanup operations, such as flushing the open C files.

This is visible in this case only when writing to file, as when writing to a tty stdout is line-buffered by default, so it's flushed immediately. When redirecting to file, instead, the data is just copied in a temporary buffer, to be flushed when it's full enough, or at termination - but the C runtime cleanup functions aren't ever called in your case, so the data is never actually passed to the OS.

Another possibility is to exit using the `exit` libc function (`extern exit` at the beginning and `call exit` at the end of the execution), which should handle the cleanup, <del>but I'm not sure if stuff from libc is even required to work fine if it doesn't get the chance to be initialized in first place</del> should be safe on Linux, see *@PeterCordes* comment and thanks to *@Kirill_Zaitsev* for trying it.

Comment: glibc startup code runs before `_start` in a *dynamically* linked executable on Linux (using `.init` hooks); that's not the problem.  (It's generally not recommended to use libc from _start, but it's actually fully safe in a dynamic Linux executable, as far as I know.  It doesn't work on Cygwin, which is maybe why some people recommend against it?).  Only exiting without flushing stdio when it's full-buffered is the problem.

Comment: @PeterCordes @MatteoItalia Is there a way to use the good old main without compiling with `gcc` but only with `ld` ?

Comment: @Alrick: yes, if you pass all the same options to `ld` that gcc does, including the `.o` files that define `_start`.  Or write your own `_start` that calls your `main` and then passes the return value to libc `exit(3)`.  (e.g. [How Get arguments value using inline assembly in C without Glibc?](//stackoverflow.com/q/50260855) where Matteo posted a truly minimal `_start` which uses sys_exit, you could modify that to `call exit` instead.)  But IDK why you would, just use gcc's front-end to run `as` and `ld` and link in the CRT startup code.

Comment: @Alrick Not possible in a portable manner.  Try to avoid using `ld` directly unless you know exactly what you are doing.