# Using ftrace on simple program, Inline Assembly __asm__("leave") resulting in seg fault

Tags: c, gcc, x86, inline-assembly, ftrace

I am reading through this book on learning Linux Binary Analysis. In the book the author presents ftrace, which he has on his github and demonstrates how to use it. He provides a small bit of code with which to test the ftrace.

When running the ftrace on it, nothing happens. If I run the executable on its own I just get a seg fault.
I am compiling it like so: gcc -nostdlib test.c -o test

**Here's the code I have:**

```
int foo(void) {  
}

_start()
{
    foo();
    __asm__("leave");
}
```

The expected results demonstrate the ftrace tracing the function calls through the execution.

**Here's an image from the text of what I'm going off of:**

[image: simple ftrace]

**Here is the ftrace I'm using:**

https://github.com/elfmaster/ftrace

I guess the question is, am I missing something completely, doing something wrong, is the text outdated or what would be the correct approach to this? I apologize if this is a dumb question, I was just going off the text. I also tried this with a 32bit distro on a VM and nothing changed, but just tried it because some of the author's examples are on 32bit. Thank you.

**Note:** When I run his ftrace with a program that doesn't cause a seg fault I get

```
pid_read() failed: Input/output error <0x1>
```

Comment: *I also tried this with a 32bit distro on a VM.* You never need that, just add `-m32` to the gcc command-line to make 32-bit code / executables.  (All modern distros have multilib packages for gcc/libc that install 32-bit versions of libc and other key libraries that 32-bit executables need on a normal 64-bit system.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Oh okay, awesome thank you. I'll do that from now on.

Comment: IIRC, the _start function is not supposed to return (there is no return address on the stack anymore). It supposed to call the exit system call explicitly. Also, the `leave` is going to change the `rsp`. Why are you inserting the `leave`?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I was going off the example in the book, I assumed that the leave was causing the seg fault. But like I said I was asking if the approach from the text is outdated. Since the author showed his ftrace working with the small program.

Comment: And fun fact: `gcc -nostdlib` makes a static executable.  That will work even if you *don't* have 32-bit libraries installed.  All you need is kernel support for 32-bit processes and system calls.  (Missing on Windows WSL, otherwise widespread.)  And of course you need a 32-bit executable with containing useful machine code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `_exit(0);` or `exit_group(0)` at the end of `_start`.  (Link with `gcc -static -nostartfiles` instead of `-nostdlib` so you can call the libc system call wrapper functions; they should work even though glibc init functions haven't been run [so malloc or printf would crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54507957/printf-call-from-assembly-do-not-print-to-stdout) ).

Or make an `exit_group(0)` system-call manually with inline asm.  On x86-64 Linux:
**`asm("mov $231, %eax; xor %edi,%edi; syscall");`**

See also [How Get arguments value using inline assembly in C without Glibc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50260855/how-get-arguments-value-using-inline-assembly-in-c-without-glibc/50283880#50283880) for more about writing a hacky x86-64 `_start` to run your own C function as the first thing in your process.  (But most of that answer is about hacking the calling convention to access argc / argv, which is nasty and I don't recommend it.)  Matteo's answer on that question has a whole minimal `_start` written in asm that calls a normal C `main` function.

---

**The book's code is just plain broken for 2 reasons**.  (I don't know how it could have ever worked on i386 or x86-64.  Seems super weird to me.  Are you sure it wasn't just supposed to crash, but you look at what it does before that happens?)

1. **`_start` is not a function in Linux; you (or compiler-generated code) can't `ret` from it**.  You need to make an `_exit` system call.  There is no return address on the stack<sup>1</sup>.

   Where a function would have its return address, the ELF entry point `_start` has `argc`, as specified in the ABI docs.  (x86-64 System V or i386 System V depending on whether you build a 64-bit or `gcc -m32` 32-bit executable.)
2. **Inserting `leave`** (which does `mov %ebp, %esp` / `pop %ebp` or the RBP / RSP equivalent) **into the compiler-generated code** makes no sense here.  It's sort of like an extra `pop`, but breaks the compiler's `EBP`/`RBP` so if it happens to choose `leave` instead of `pop %rbp` for its own prologue then the compiler generated code will fault.  (RBP on entry to `_start` is 0 in a  statically-linked executable.  Or holding whatever the dynamic linker left in RBP before jumping to `_start` in a PIE executable.)

   But ultimately, GCC will compile `_start` as a normal function, thus eventually running a `ret` instruction.  There is no valid / useful return address anywhere, so there's no way `ret` can work at all.

   If you compile without optimization (the default), gcc will default to `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`, so its function prologue will have set up EBP or RBP as a frame pointer making it possible for `leave` itself to not fault.  If you compiled with optimization (`-O1` and higher enables `-fomit-frame-pointer`), gcc wouldn't be messing with RBP, and it would be zero when you ran `leave`, thus directly causing a segfault.  (Because it does RSP=RBP and then uses the new RSP as the stack pointer for `pop %rbp`.)

Anyway, if it doesn't fault, that will leave the stack pointer pointing to `argc` again, before the compiler-generated `pop %rbp` as part of the normal function epilogue.  **So the compiler-generated `ret` will try to return to `argv[0]`.  Since the stack is non-executable by default, that will segfault.**  (And it's pointing to ASCII characters, which probably don't decode as useful x86-64 machine code.)

You could have found this out yourself by single-stepping the asm with GDB.  (`layout reg` and use `stepi` aka `si`).

In general you messing with the stack pointer and other registers behind the compiler's back will typically just make things crash.  And if there had been a return address higher up on the stack, `pop %rcx` would make a lot more sense than `leave`.

---

Footnote 1:

There's not even any machine code anywhere in the address space of your process that a useful return address *could* point to to make such a system call, unless you inject some machine code as an arg or environment variable.

You linked with `-nostdlib` so there's no libc linked.  If you did link libc dynamically but still wrote your own `_start` (e.g. with `gcc -nostartfiles` instead of the full `-nostdlib`), ASLR would mean the libc `_exit` function was at some runtime-variable address.

If you statically linked libc (`gcc -nostartfiles -static`), the code for `_exit()` wouldn't be copied into your executable unless you actually referenced it, which this code doesn't.  But you still need to get it called somehow; there's no return address pointing to it.

Comment: Wow, thank you. I appreciate the explanation. Does his ftrace work for you or is that incorrect as well?

Comment: @Camilo: I have no idea, I'm not familiar with ftrace.  I didn't try running the executable or even compiling it; I just pictured in my head what GCC's asm would do for a trivial function compiled in debug mode vs. optimized.  If you want to look at the compiler-generated asm, put it on https://godbolt.org/

Comment: Okay, I'll check out godbolt.org thanks again for the in-depth explanation.

Comment: @Camilo: since you say this got published in a book, I tried to think of ways where it could possibly work.  But I really don't see anything even plausible, unless the state of memory and registers on entry to `_start` was very very different back in ancient history, like maybe in `a.out` days before the switch to ELF.

Comment: @Camilo: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info has lots of good links, especially for performance tuning but also for understanding x86 asm for other reasons.  Including links to docs for assemblers, ABIs, and x86 ISA official docs.