# falling in segmentation fault in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault

I am trying to print each charactere after a comma with printf, but it gives me segmentation fault

```
global main

extern printf

section .data
        num db "%d",0
        array db 2,4,3
        arrlen equ $ - array

section .text
main:
        mov ecx, 0

mainloop:
        cmp ecx, arrlen
        je exit

        movzx ebx, byte [array + ecx]
        push ebx
        push num
        call printf

        add esp, 8

        inc ecx
        jmp mainloop

exit:
        mov eax, 1
        xor ebx, ebx
        int 0x80
```

I tried even to use chatGPT xd

Comment: `ecx` is not preserved across calls according to standard calling convention. Use `esi` or `edi`. Also note you should not use `int 0x80` to terminate the program especially if you did not use a line feed in the format as that will not flush buffers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ECX is not a call-preserved register. `printf` probably modifies it so your ECX-based loop runs for too long, hence addressing memory beyond the array.
Try using EBX that is a call-preserved register:

```
main:
        xor   ebx, ebx
        jmp   beginloop
mainloop:
        movzx eax, byte [array + ebx]
        push  eax
        push  num
        call  printf
        add   esp, 8
        inc   ebx
beginloop:
        cmp   ebx, arrlen
        jb    mainloop
exit:
        mov   eax, 1
        xor   ebx, ebx
        int   0x80
```

Comment: hello! i ran this version of the code but the array characteres were not displayed :/

Comment: @spyblock Did you change to using the `exit` function as @Jester suggested?

Comment: @ecm sure, i ran the entire code with this new one

Comment: No, not the code with the label `exit` in the answer's example. Read the comment by @Jester on your question, if you `call printf` you should also `call exit` with an `extern exit`

Comment: @spyblock: That part is a duplicate of [Using printf in assembly leads to empty output when piping, but works on the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38379553) (except it fails even on the terminal because no newline.)  The other part is [What are callee and caller saved registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56178078) , and probably a duplicate somewhere about ECX in 32-bit calling conventions

Comment: @ecm now with the exit it runs, thank you guys